# Prevent fixed header to overlapp content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am stuck with this problem, I have a responsive fixed header that is overlapping the main content!

I am using internal/anchor linking on the same page. Both from the nav-menu/header links and from the [VERTIAL DOT NAVIGATION](http://www.jqueryscript.net/menu/jQuery-Plugin-For-Smooth-Vertical-Scrolling-Navigation.html) Jquery plugin. I am not able to link to the different sections without the header overlapping the first 60px of the section. I have been trying to add `margin-top: 60px;` to the .container and .section-top class with no success.

I would like to be able to link both from the nav-menu/header links and the jQuery dot navigation, without the header overlapping with 60px.

See this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xm7gyqLz/1/) for more!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add this:

```
[id^="section"]{
  padding-top: 60px;
}
```

and remove this

```
 .section-top {
  margin-top: 60px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/w8u2kg1j/

Comment: Thanks a lot! Happy New year!

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following CSS, to have the header overlap with only the padding area:

```
section {
  padding-top:60px;
}
```